# How to remove none from pie chart in matplotlib chart?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I'm trying to make visualization of data using pandas. Here is my code where plt is Matplotlib.

```
meets = results.groupby(['Meet']).size()
meets.dropna()
plt.figure(figsize=(14,14))
meets.plot(kind='pie',autopct='%.2f',fontsize=20,title='Причина знакомства с Доктором',legend=True,labels=None)
plt.show()
```

With this code i get this pie chart with none label. 
[image]
How to remove this label?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set it to an empty string before calling `show` or `savefig`:

```
plt.ylabel("")
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an attribute in plot function called label, which you can set:

`meets.plot(kind='pie',autopct='%.2f',fontsize=20,title='Причина знакомства с Доктором',legend=True,label="")`